# Firefox losing CodeIgniter session variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, firefox

I've a php-codeigniter program which sets some session variables when starts, so on a second page the system sets some other session variables (lista, validacao, classe, metodo, tipo) and redirects for a third page, so in this third page all the sessions variables are correctly, but when I click on a link in this page which sends to a fourth page which lost the sessions variables which was setted in the second page.

I tested this pages in Google Chrome, IE and Firefox, but this problem only happens in Firefox.

Print of the session in the second page:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => d964bc724d3fc680c345d0fd2cd451d8
    [ip_address] => 192.168.101.151
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
    [last_activity] => 1390564837
    [user_data] => 
    [qtdeambientes] => 1
    [nomesibe] => Portal SIBE
    [nomeambiente] => 
    [sibe] => 2
    [ambiente] => 12
    [nomeusuario] => magno
    [tipotabela] => D
    [logado] => 1
    [codigousuario] => 1377
    [codigosetor] => 42
    [tipousuario] => C
    [codigotabela] => 235
    [codigodistribuidor] => 235
    [id_grupo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
        )

    [lista] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
        )

    [validacao] => 1
    [classe] => distribuidora/menudistribuidora
    [metodo] => cliente
    [tipo] => G
)
```

Print of the session in the fourth page:
See that variables defined on the second page disappeared.

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => d964bc724d3fc680c345d0fd2cd451d8
    [ip_address] => 192.168.101.151
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
    [last_activity] => 1390564837
    [user_data] => 
    [qtdeambientes] => 1
    [nomesibe] => Portal SIBE
    [nomeambiente] => 
    [sibe] => 2
    [ambiente] => 12
    [nomeusuario] => magno
    [tipotabela] => D
    [logado] => 1
    [codigousuario] => 1377
    [codigosetor] => 42
    [tipousuario] => C
    [codigotabela] => 235
    [codigodistribuidor] => 235
    [id_grupo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
        )

)
```

Comment: CodeIgniter session are serialized data stored in cookies, unless you have you set them to save in the database. The problem with cookies is they have a file size limit (4kb I think), it might be possible that the serialized information is exceeding this size and is being "trimmed" so it appears to be losing data

Comment: I changed my session configuration to storage at the database for cookie and my problem was temporarily solved. But how I need storage at the database, this is not a valid solution.